# Concurrent symmetric difference

Tags: concurrency, semaphore, symmetric-difference

I have tutorials on my university about cuncurrent programming.
My task is to write a program based on semaphores in which a symmetric
difference of two sets of numbers will be computed. I can't see where
the concurrent programming is necessary. I understand that CP is about
using same resources of data, but in which phase I should use two
threads and semaphore. Semaphores are used to hold some process which
may interfere the data, that are used by other process. I just don't
see it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The input sets are read-only, so your multiple threads will not step on each-others' toes (except maybe for memory bus contention), but you will need to synchronize your threads as they write into the result set.